# Large gaps between paragaphs VS avoiding widows / orphans

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, widows-orphans

How to avoid widow and orphan lines, while also avoiding too large gaps appearing between the paragraphs on the previous page?

I figure that to strongly discourage widows and orphans, one would use a high but not infinite `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` value, such as

```
\clubpenalty=9996
\widowpenalty=8500
```

This in turn makes TeX to stretch the spaces between the paragraphs on the previous page, and one tries to strike the balance with penalties, so that the extra paragraph gaps are usually not noticeable.

However sometimes the difference on facing pages is really noticeable, are there other techniques or internals penalties to avoid this?

What are the manual correction techniques apart from `\raggedbottom` and `\enlargethispage`?

Comment: Related questions: [LaTeX produces bad, widowed line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7634/1235) and [How do I prevent widow/orphan lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4152/1235)

Comment: It may be a bit lame but when I encounter widows or orphans, I simply encourage my creativity and add a couple of sentences or do finishing touches. No general solution has worked for me every time so far.

Comment: @Harrold: this is the approach taken by Knuth himself, so it has some precedent. I don't have the reference in front of me, but I remember he wrote he found it valuable to force himself to rewrite a sentence to avoid a bad break because he has almost always found a way to improve wording of the sentence in the process.

Comment: @Lev: Suddenly my approach does not seem that odd to me any more, thank you for the information, Lev. It is indeed true that I often find better wording while eliminating widows and orphans manually so paradoxically, the lack of a general automatic solution comes handy, in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to set `\looseness=1` or `\looseness=-1` to make certain paragraphs one line longer or shorter, respectively. This is described in the TeXbook on page 103-104.

Comment: With `\looseness=1` you normally need to put a few `~` between the last few words of the paragraph, or you'll end up with one-word final lines of paragraphs, which is not much of an improvement.

Comment: This can help to avoid those: `\parfillskip 0pt plus 0.75\textwidth` as suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/widow-word-on-a-page-i-thought-latex-wouldnt-do-that/3130#3130). There might still be club words left, since stretching the lines of an already loosened paragraph might have even higher penalty than ending up with a club word.

Comment: Thanks, loosening a few large paragraphs on the problematic page really does the job.