# Last sentence broken between two pages

Tags: formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Widow *word* on a page? I thought LaTeX wouldn't do that.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/widow-word-on-a-page-i-thought-latex-wouldnt-do-that)

Hello,
there is following text:

```
Some text, some text, .... This sentence probably will be broken.
```

And the output is like:

Previous page:

```
Some text, some text, .... This sentence probably will
```

On top of next page:

```
be broken.
```

It doesn't look nice when some small remainders of last sentence or last sentences are displayed on the top of next page. I know that I can use for example \newpage, but it is often hard to say when new page will appear. Is there some way to automatically make it better? For example to push some content from previous page to the next page which will prevent to appear single words on the next page.

Comment: see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=widows

Comment: Possible duplicate to these questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/latex-produces-bad-widowed-line, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/widow-word-on-a-page-i-thought-latex-wouldnt-do-that

Answer (score 1):

See the tex faq about widows and orphans:
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widows